# Why once I've declared a reference as a const then it can take a different type of data?

Tags: c++, oop

Hello i'm trying to figure out this thing..

Say i have this code.

```
int a = 5;
double& b = a; //Error.
```

Then once I've declared the second line as a const the compiler doesn't complain anymore.

```
const double& b = a; //Correct.
```

what is really going on behind the scene, why const solves the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's happening behind the scenes is an implicit conversion of
an int to a double.  The result of an implicit conversion is not
an lvalue, so it cannot be used to initialize a non-const
reference.

Comment: good answer, but do you think in general that those who ask about this know the definition of an lvalue?

Comment: @JohanLundberg, in general that people may find another SO question "what is lvalue"

Answer (score 7):

An `int` needs to be converted to `double` first. That conversion yields a prvalue temporary and these can't bind to references to non-const.

A reference to const will extend the lifetime of the temporary that would otherwise be destroyed at the end of the expression it was created in.

```
{
    int a = 0;
    float f = a; // a temporary float is created here, its value is copied to
                 // f and then it dies
    const double& d = a; // a temporary double is created here and is bound to 
                         // the const-ref
}   // and here it dies together with d
```

If you're wondering what a prvalue is, here's a nice [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues) about value categories.